# background is pushed down in Chrome and Safari

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, background

I used "320andup" in order to make my first real responsive website. I managed to have a perfect adaptive environment except only one thing. The background image in Chrome and Safari is pushed down 18px. I can't explain why. Only thing I know is that when i add in the body tag "background-attachment: fixed;" the problem is solved but when I scroll  I get an ugly experience that I don't want to have. I also tried this

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { 
    body {
    background-image: url(../img/chrome-safari-img.gif);
    }
}
```

with IE to completely break.

Firefox, Opera and IE8 are ok. Only problem is Chrome and Safari.

You can see exactly whats the problem and investigate the code in my localhost website -> http://www.demo.lollypop.gr/ffloor

I would like to avoid detecting chrome with PHP.

Comment: I really can't understand why I got -1 for my question.

Comment: Yeah, downvotes without an explanation is super rude.

Comment: I have spend many hours searching for a work around, thats why I can't understand -1. I guess it was to obvious to see the fix... Thank you all for taking a minute to help me out in this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `position:absolute;` in your body tag.

Comment: I am feeling very stupid right now. Thank you very very much for your help.

Comment: No problem, stuff like this happens to me all the time. We work too much. :-)